# What causes this strange convergent sum?

Tags: summation

```
N[Sum[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, 1, Infinity}], 5]
N[Sum[1/(x^2 + x + 1), {x, 1, Infinity}], 5]
```

1.0767

0.79815 + 0.*10^-6 I

What causes the strange number?

Comment: Note that your strange number $0. \times 10^{-6} \mathbf{i}$ is, within the precision you specified, equal to 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note that Mathematica *can* do the symbolic sums:

```
Sum[1/(x^2 + 1), {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives

$$
    \frac{1}{2} (-1 + \pi \coth[\pi])
$$

and

```
Sum[1/(x^2 + x + 1), {x, 1, Infinity}]
```

gives

$$
-\frac{i \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(1+\sqrt[3]{-1}\right)-\psi ^{(0)}\left(1-(-1)^{2/3}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{3}}
$$
(where $\psi^{(0)}(x)$ is `PolyGamma[0,x]`, and in fact if you apply `FullSimplify` this can be written in terms of `HarmonicNumber` as well). But you are asking for numeric versions of these to a specific number of significant figures. To that precision, the imaginary parts of the latter function do not quite cancel, and hence you get a small imaginary part.

Note also that using `NSum[...]` instead of `N[Sum[...]]` works better here, since it actually does the numerical sum by adding the terms, as opposed to calculating the symbolic form and then numerically evaluating it.

Comment: (+1) but one note for completeness: in cases where `Sum` _can't_ solve the sum symbolically (not applicable here), `N[Sum[...]` seems to be equivalent to `NSum[...]` according to the docs for `NSum`.

Comment: Is there any reason that PolyGamma is used for this number as opposed to the first number?

Comment: Infinite sums are like integrals: even seemingly simple expressions can have complicated answers, and similar expressions can have very different answers.

Comment: @FredKline This question http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/how-to-eliminate-the-zero-real-part-of-a-purely-imaginary-number discusses a related issue in `Mathematica 8` and `9`.

Answer (score 7):

There are several methods in `Sum` which may help in various cases. To find your second sum symbolically in apparently real form you can try, e.g.

```
Sum[1/(1 + x + x^2), {x, 1, Infinity}, Method -> "HypergeometricTermPFQ"]
```

[image]

However there are still other ways to get the same result without methods specified, e.g. :

```
s = Sum[1/(1 + x + x^2), {x, 1, Infinity}];

FullSimplify[ ComplexExpand //@ s ]
```

or

```
FullSimplify @ ExpToTrig @ s
```

Note that we had to [`MapAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MapAll.html?q=MapAll&lang=en) (shorthand `//@`) `ComplexExpand` i.e. apply the latter to every subexpression of  `s`