# How to eliminate the zero real part of a purely imaginary number?

Tags: output-formatting, complex

In *Mathematica 9*, a purely imaginary number, e.g. `0.9 I`, will display as `0. + 0.9i` in the output form. How can I eliminate the real part `0.` in the output form?

Comment: To get rid of `0.` you should use e.g. `4/5 I`.

Comment: You could use `Round` if the precision isn't of importance.

Comment: Interesting, `Chop` doesn't do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a specific issue of `Mathematica 9`, we have the same in `ver.8` 
unlike in `ver.7`.

**Mathematica 8 and 9**

First, looking at `FullForm` of these numbers :

```
FullForm /@ {0.9 I, 0 + 0.9 I, 0.9 + 0 I, 0.9 + 0. I}
```

> ```
> {Complex[0.`, 0.9`], Complex[0.`, 0.9`], 0.9`, Complex[0.9`, 0.`]}
> ```

(see e.g. [Meaning of backtick in floating-point literal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2915/meaning-of-backtick-in-floating-point-literal))
 and then examining this behvior :

```
{ Complex[0, 9/10], Complex[0, 0.9], Complex[0.9, 0], Complex[0.9, 0.]}
  Chop @ %
```

> ```
> {(9 I)/10, 0. + 0.9 I, 0.9, 0.9 + 0. I}
> {(9 I)/10, 0. + 0.9 I, 0.9, 0.9       }
> ```

we can conclude that assuming the real part as an exact number it will be rewritten as a machine precission number given that the imaginary part is a machine precision number. Reverse need not be always true because e.g. `Head[ Complex[0.9, 0]]` is `Real` unlike `Head[ Complex[0.9, 0.]]`. Perhaps one might consider this as a bug since `Chop` unexpectedly doesn't work on the real part, while it works for the imaginary part in the above example. On the other hand rewriting `Complex[0, .9]` as `0. + 0.9I` may be considered as a consistency issue.

Nevertheless you can still get the expected result using e.g. `RootApproximant` :

```
RootApproximant[0.9 I]
```

> ```
> (9 I)/10
> ```

However if the imaginary part is not an algebraic number you cannot expect that `RootApproximant` will appear helpful and you'll have to work with exact numbers from the begining, e.g. this works well `RootApproximant[ Sqrt[2.] I]` while this doesn't `RootApproximant[Pi  I]`, nevertheless one needn't use it at all (`Pi  I` yields `I π`).

```
{0 + Pi I, 0. + Pi I}
```

> ```
> { I π, 0. + 3.14159 I}
> ```

**Mathematica 7**

We have in `ver.7` :

```
FullForm[0.9 I]
```

> ```
> Complex[0, 0.9`]
> ```

therefore :

```
0.9 I
```

> ```
> 0.9 I
> ```

nevertheless this behavior is not quite consistent, e.g. :

```
{ π I, 0. + π I, π + 0 I, π + 0. I}
```

> ```
> {I π, 0. + 3.14159 I, π, 3.14159 + 0. I}
> ```

there is even **worse problem** :

```
{Pi + 0.9 I, Complex[Pi, 0.9]}
```

> ```
> {3.14159 + 0.9 I, Complex[π, 0.9]}
> ```

To sum up the behaviour in `Mathematica 8` and `9` seems to be more uniform than that of `Mathematica 7` and therefore one can say it is an intentional issue. On the other hand `Chop` works well in `ver. 7` :

```
{ Complex[0., 0.9], Complex[0.9, 0], Complex[0.9, 0.]}
 Chop @ %
```

> ```
>  {0. + 0.9 I, 0.9, 0.9 + 0. I}
>  {0.9 I, 0.9, 0.9}
> ```

while its defect in `ver.8` and `9` is definitely undesirable.

Comment: @Rojo Thanks, just for completeness : In `ver.7` `Complex[Pi, 0.9]` returns the same unlike `Pi + 0.9 I`, which yields `3.14159 + 0.9 I`. Thus it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to have this problem in version 7:  `0.9 I` outputs as `0.9 i` where the `i` is the double-struck `\[ImaginaryI]`.  Further `FullForm[0.9 I]` yields `` Complex[0, 0.9`] ``.

Nevertheless I would try:

```
MakeBoxes[Verbatim[Complex][r_, i_] /; r == 0, fmt_] := 
  MakeBoxes[#, fmt] & @ Row @ {i, "\[MediumSpace]\[ImaginaryI]"}
```

Comment: In v7 ``Complex[2, 3`]``, ``Complex[2`, 3]`` both keep their exact parts exact?

Comment: @Rojo That's correct.

Comment: Interesting... In v9 it only happens for machine precision. It can keep mixed stuff but only if the precision is explicit. Keep your v7 :P

Comment: @Rojo  The same behaviour is in `ver.8` while in `ver.7` that is not quite consistent.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If I want machine-precision purely imaginary numbers formatted without the real part, all I need to do is use your `MakeBoxes` once?  Are there any side-effects or is this just cosmetic? (thinking of including this invocation in a package, but don't want any unexpected consequences)