# Mysterious behavior of Precision for complex arrays

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Mysterious behavior of `Precision`:

```
{{1.0+I*0.0},{0.0+I*0.0}} // SetPrecision[#,30]& // Precision // Print;
```

> ```
> 0.
> ```

```
{{1.0},{0.0}} // SetPrecision[#,30]& // Precision // Print;
```

> ```
> 30.
> ```

Why is the precision zero in the first instance, but not the second?

This led to some tough-to-diagnose program behaviors!

Comment: This seems to be closely related: [How to eliminate the zero real part of a purely imaginary number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/how-to-eliminate-the-zero-real-part-of-a-purely-imaginary-number/17819#17819).

Comment: It seems like the `0.0+I*0.0` is the culprit. Try `I // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision`,
`1 // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision`,
`0 // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision`,
`0.0 // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision`,
`0.0 I // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision` and especially pay attention to the last two. I assume that `Precision` when applied to an array takes the minimum of the precisions of the elements of the array; the first element of `{{1.0+I*0.0},{0.0+I*0.0}}` has precision 30, whereas the second has precision 0, so the result is 0, but I'm not sure why `0.0I` has precision 0.

Comment: And there's also precision Infinity: f[x_] := x // SetPrecision[#, 30] & // Precision;
{f[0], f[0.0], f[0.0 + 0.0 I], f[1.0], f[1.0 I]} gives {\[Infinity], \[Infinity], 0., 30., 30.}

Answer (score 1):

Not receiving an answer, the following "workaround" returns Precision as a rounded-up integer multiple of MachinePrecision:

```
Precision$TNS[arg_] := arg//
  Precision//
    Which[
        NumberQ[#] && (#>0.0),
        {#},
        True,
        {arg}//Flatten//
          Map[Precision,#]&//
            Select[#,(NumberQ[#] && (#>0.0))&]&
    ]&//Max[#,MachinePrecision]&//
      (#-1)/MachinePrecision&//Ceiling//
        #*MachinePrecision&;
```

This workaround suffices (seemingly) for my main purpose, which is to assess and if necessary adaptively increase the precision of large-condition Real and Complex array arguments that are supplied to SingularValueDecomposition[_].