# What makes imaginary parts show up?

Tags: list-manipulation, complex

If I define a function using

```
alpha[y_, d_] := 2 ArcCos[1 - (2 y)/d]
```

Then if $y$ and $d$ are equal, the result is $2\pi$ :

```
alpha[x, x]
```

and

```
alpha[4, 4]
```

are both evaluated as

> $2 \pi$

But when I use this in a table with:

`Table[alpha[y1, d1], {d1, 0.1, 5, 0.1}, {y1, 0, d1, 0.1}]`

Some imaginary parts (although very small) for example $6.28319 - 5.96046*10^-8 i$ appear. Am I doing something wrong? It seems like something basic that I am doing wrong because of not understanding a concept in MMA.

Comment: Prolly just your machine's floating point arithmetic. On my box, I'm not getting tiny imaginary parts at all (10.4 on Xubuntu Trusty). Note that the evaluation of arccosine is ill-conditioned near $\pm 1$, so tiny perturbations in the argument can cause not very small perturbations in the output.

Comment: Basically since your numbers in `Table` are approximate your problem appears to be trivial. Nevertheless if  there is a certain problem at all, it was raised in his question [How to eliminate the zero real part of a purely imaginary number?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17809/how-to-eliminate-the-zero-real-part-of-a-purely-imaginary-number).  The issue is version dependent.

Comment: @J.M. I'm using 10.3 on Windows 8. Good point about the ill-conditioned behavior.

Comment: @Artes Getting rid of this is not the point, I can eliminate it easily.  But I had this idea that  `Table` can be used to do just the same thing we are doing for one expression, more than once. I didn't know it has a built-in approximation functionality. I want to make sure I understand how things work so as to not repeat the same mistakes.

Comment: It's not `Table[]` that's doing the approximation; it's your use of `0.1`in the iterator. Try replacing all those with `1/10`, and apply `N[]` afterwards.

Comment: @J.M. Oh! Now that's the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot! It makes sense now.

Comment: Can you answer your own question now, then? :)

Comment: I think from now on I'll always use exact iterators, just in case. Interesting that I didn't see this in any introductory documents.

Comment: In general, inexact numbers "contaminate" every calculation in which they are introduced; the result's precision will be the same as that of the least precise number. In your case, the machine precision `0.1` resulted in everything being done in machine precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to [@J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) and [@Artes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/184/artes) I found out that the iterator 0.1 in the `Table` function was making this artifact, which is also version dependent.

@J. M.'s solution worked perfectly:

```
 Table[N[alpha[y1, d1]], {d1, 1/10, 5, 1/10}, {y1, 0, d1, 1/10}]
```

Comment: Specifying the precision of your iterator should also prevent the imaginary part from showing up: ``Table[alpha[y1, d1], {d1, 0.1`6, 5, 0.1`6}, {y1, 0, d1, 0.1`6}]``

Comment: @RunnyKine, thanks. If I want to use this, I guess I have to set the precision of everything else to the same order, right?

Comment: If you're using a function as in your question, then you don't need to. Setting the precision of the iterators like I did will just instruct *Mathematica* to carry out the calculation to that precision.